# Request always* takes atleast 1 second when timeout > 2

Tags: php, curl, curl-multi

Ok this is really weird.
When i do a request to my localhost (which takes about 1-2 ms), it takes curl much longer.
It seems to be depend on the timeout (lowest of ConnectionTimeout / normaltimeout).

**All the requests succeed**

- When Timeout_Ms = 5, Time for curl to comeback is around 1 Ms.
- When Timeout_Ms = 50, Time for curl to comeback is around 4 Ms.
- When Timeout_Ms = 500, Time for curl to comeback is around 250 Ms.
- When Timeout_Ms = 1000, Time for curl to comeback is around 500 Ms.
- When Timeout_Ms = 1500, Time for curl to comeback is around 750 Ms.
- When Timeout_Ms > 2000, Time for curl to comeback is around 1000 Ms.

So, when setting the timeout high, it always takes the request 1 second.
When using curl_multi, there is also 1 second added to the time, but it doesnt matter how many requests i do.

I have 2 request:

- One takes 5 seconds -> finished after 6 seconds
- Second takes 10 seconds -> finished after 11 seconds

Answer (score 0):

This is propably, because the server wants to keep the connection open for possible further request. Set the `Connection`-header to `close`. See for example http://php.net/curl.constants.php#76914

```
$header = array("Connection: close");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
```

Comment: This does not make any difference. Also why would the transfer then not take 20 seconds when my timeout is set to 20s?